# Alternativa rotativa no Azure

Tags: winforms, microsoft-azure, rotativa

Uso o rotativa no meu sistema, mas ao executar o mesmo no *Azure* como uma Web Application pois o *Azure* não permite a execução de arquivo `.exe`. Sendo assim, preciso de algum outro *Framework* que substitua o rotativa e que seja permitido no *Azure*.

Comment: poderia postar o ERRO para que a comunidade o possa ajudar

Comment: Na verdade não é um erro, gostaria de uma alternativa para o Rotativa.

Answer (score 0):

O Azure permite sim, porém terá que ser planos S1 para cima.
Ou caso queira com baixo custo, criar uma VM e hospedar manualmente.